# How to break a list of span

Tags: html, css

I have a table, and inside some cells I have few `<span>`, the `<td>` containing these span has a class with `word-wrap: break-word; white-space: normal;`.

In other words: `<td class="breakit"><span>foo</span><span>bar</span></td>`

With: `.breakit{ word-wrap: break-word; white-space: normal; }`

Well no matter how much I shrink the browser it never break the span!

Why?

Comment: So you want the spans to line up horizontally when they have room, and break up vertically when they don't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why? Because there is no white-space between foo and bar.

Put in a space, or move the bar span down a line in your HTML, and it will break.

**UPDATE**
I think I've found the real reason:

"No matter how you're specifying table width, each table has a minimum size and it will never display smaller than that size. The minimum size is calculated by the length of the longest single word in each cell."
found in : http://www.devx.com/projectcool/Article/17870/0/page/9

...and this rule appears to apply to each cell, that is, the minimum width of a cell is dictated by the longest word within it.

(this is another reason not to use tables for general layout purposes).

Comment: The whole purpose of `word-wrap: break-word;` is to allow line-breaks inside words regardless of white space.

Comment: Ah, I have learned something new. Thank you. But I've also found the real reason (I think) -- see my update.

Comment: That's the actual reason. So unless you force-change table width upon window re-size, nothing will ever happen inside table cells.

Comment: Why did it work then? I added a &thinsp; after the first span and it works.

Comment: @Tomalak, yeah but of course I was forcing refresh, and was not breaking them.

Comment: I'm guessing &thinsp; though a non-breaking space, is recognized by the browser as a word separator, so it can now find its shortest word as one of those 2 shorter strings of text instead of the whole string, and set its min-width as shorter.

Comment: @MaxFavilli As long as you don't specify an exact width for your table/td, the browser sees little reason to wrap words needlessly. adding a (thin) space makes the word breakable. Adding a `<span>` doesn't.

Comment: @Tomalak: but even if you do set both the cell and table width very narrow in CSS, it won't work, apparently because of this minimum width rule. ... that is, without something to break the string into 2 words. See: http://jsfiddle.net/qRC9Q/1/

Comment: @Faust You must use fixed table layout to force widths: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/qRC9Q/2/

Comment: @MaxFavilli: `&thinsp;` is like normal space (definitely breaking), just thinner. If you wish to use such a method (which has some issues), it is better to use `&#x200b;`, the zero-width space.

Comment: Guys I learnt a lot more than I was expecting, I love stackoverflow, I love you.